# how to convert linq to xml query to string[]

Tags: c#, xml, linq

here is my xml:

```
<record>
<id>12342</id>
<name>xx</name>
<blah1>asdfas</blah1>
<blah2>asdfas</blah2>
.....
</record>
```

I would like to get all of the values and put it into a array.
i tried the following, it returns "12342xxasdfasasdfas" instead of "12342","xx","asdfas","asdfas"

```
  var q = record.Elements("record").Select(r=>r.Value);
 string[] array = q.ToArray();
```

i have come up the solution by using foreach loop, just wondering if there are any better ways to do that?

```
var q2 = record.Descendants("record").Elements();
int length = Convert.ToInt32(q2.Count().ToString());
string[] array2 =new string[length];
int i = 0;
                foreach (XElement e in q2)
                {
                    array2[i] = e.Value;
                   i++; 
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extract all the text elements, look for the `XText` nodes in the structure and extract their values:

```
string[] array = record.DescendantNodes()
                       .Where(n => n.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text)
                       .Select(n => ((XText) n).Value)
                       .ToArray();
```

Result in your example: "12342", "xx", "asdfas", "asdfas", "..."

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
string[] result = (from item in record.Descendants("record").Elements()
                  select item.Value).ToArray();
```

Comment: This only works if the text we’re looking for is in an immediate child node of `<record>`. Granted, the example is like that, but the question didn’t state that it should be limited that way.

Comment: I'm just answering the question not imagining things that might be required